# pandas.read_table - preceding zeros of numbers are removed

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When I read a file which contains in a column int numbers with preceding zeros into a dataframe, then the zeros are removed. How can I prevent this?

Example:

file: "`test.txt`" has the following content:

```
one two three
a 025700 's'
b 005930 7
cc 125945 hi
ddd 000003 9.0
```

Now I am reading it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "test.txt"
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=" ")
```

The output is:

```
print(df)

   one     two three
0    a   25700   's'
1    b    5930     7
2   cc  125945    hi
3  ddd       3   9.0
```

I would like to have as the content of the dataframe second column the same content as in the file:

```
   one      two three
0    a   025700   's'
1    b   005930     7
2   cc   125945    hi
3  ddd   000003   9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dtype` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=" ", dtype={'two': str})
print(df)

# Output
   one     two three
0    a  025700   's'
1    b  005930     7
2   cc  125945    hi
3  ddd  000003   9.0
```

Or if you don't want Pandas to infer your data types:

```
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep=" ", dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple/easy way is to convert columns to str.

```
df['two'] = df['two'].astype(str).str.zfill(8)
```

Same as above but, auto-calculating the required max_lenght

```
max_length = df['two'].astype(str).str.len().max()
df['two'] = df['two'].astype(str).str.zfill(max_length)
```

Comment: Instead of `pad` you can use `zfill` in this case.

Comment: And replace your 2 first lines by `max_length = df['two'].astype(str).str.len().max()` :)